# WooCommerce - How to put a checkbox label into order mails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I found the following code to add a checkbox to the checkout page to remove the tax. Everything is going fine so far. I would need a function for this so that the checkbox label is also included in the order e-mails. Can someone help?

The whole thing runs via a plugin.

```
//=============================================================================
// ADD TAX EXEMPT CHECKMARK
// =============================================================================
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'qd_tax_exempt');

function qd_tax_exempt( $checkout ) {

  echo '<div id="qd-tax-exempt"><h3>'.__('Tax Exempt').'</h3>';

  woocommerce_form_field( 'shipping_method_tax_exempt', array(
      'type'          => 'checkbox',
      'class'         => array(),
      'label'         => __('My organization is tax exempt.'),
      'required'  => false,
      ), $checkout->get_value( 'shipping_method_tax_exempt' ));

  echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review');
function taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review( $post_data ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);

  parse_str($post_data);

  if ( isset($shipping_method_tax_exempt) && $shipping_method_tax_exempt == '1')
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included some text in the email so my client would know what the checkboxes were for as well as the "value" of the checkbox. You'd just swap out your field value name.

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'madcow_waiver_boxes_for_email', 10, 3);
function madcow_waiver_boxes_for_email($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text) {
    $terms_agree = esc_html($order->get_meta('terms_agree')); ?>
<h2>Checkbox Information</h2>
<ul style="padding-left: 5px;">
    <li><strong>I understand blah blah blah</strong>
    <?php
    if ($terms_agree == 1) {
        echo 'Yes';
    } ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
}
```